# How can i get database values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, select, while-loop

I am a little blank about the next thing. I am afraid I am not approaching the problem like it should. I have a multidimensional array to show editors in a custom cms. It looks like this:

```
$options = array(
array("template","Design skelet","Selecteer het gewenste design","text","false",array("front","content","subcontent","action","special","system"),"true"),
array("is_menu","Menu item","Selecteer de gewenste plaats in het menu","select","false",$catch_menu_sec['alias'],"true"),
array("category","Pagina categorie","Voeg hier de pagina naam in","text","false","","true"),
);
```

The `$options` are stored like this:

`$option[0]` = database value.

`$option[1]` = readable value for frontend in the cms.

`$option[2]` = description for the cms user.

`$option[3]` = type of editor (textarea, text or select)

`$option[4]` = if the editor has special options.

`$option[5]` = **where the problem is. Here are the values stored for the options for the select input.

`$option[6]` = if the field is shown in the cms.

Right now i have a problem with `$option[5]`. I want to retrieve database values, so that I can get a dropdown list for every menu item in the database. `$option[5]` is used to create a secundair menu or even tertaire, where you can select the menu item where it should be a child of.

the html output I want it to be is like this:

```
<select name="is_menu">
    <option name="true">True</option>  <- basic option to set it in primair menu, coming from the array
    <option name="false">False</option>  <- basic option, coming from the array
    <option name="home">Home</option>  <- database value, coming from the array
</select>
```

I know i cannot place while or foreach loops in an array, but how can i approach this problem otherwise?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I have basic knowledge of PHP within this area, so don't be harsh on my bad explantion please :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Your Array do not contain seven elements. It only have 3 Elements. But I think you want the 5th part of each array inside the $options array (e.g. `$option[1][5]`)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** To get sub-arrays in your DB records, either use a left join and `GROUP_CONCAT()`, or do two queries, one to the main table for your rows, then one to your related table (using the ids from the first result in your `WHERE`) to add to the first set. This is *much* easier if you construct your result arrays using the unique/primary key as the index; you can then use `array_keys()` for the second query, and be able to address rows in the first result by id when adding the related records.

---

Don't use ‘magic numbers’, make each array in `$options` an associative array like this:

```
$options = [
    [
        'db_val' => 'template',
        'label' => 'Design skelet',
        ...
    ],
    ...
];
```

Then you can iterate your arrays:

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
    ...
    echo '<select name="', $option['db_val'], '">';
    foreach ($option['select_opts'] as $select_opt => $label) {
        echo '<option value="', $select_opt, '">', $label, '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ...
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner than i did yes. Thanks! Problem of the database values in the array still stands unfortunally, since this does not work.

Comment: As written, the question appeared to be about issues iterating loops.

Comment: The question is about how to get database values in the array loop :)

Comment: Don't. Get your values before you iterate otherwise you're using *n + 1* selects. There are many resources explaining why one shouldn't do this, [here's one](https://phoenixjiangnan.github.io/2016/04/25/database/The-N-1-Query-Problem/).